# proxy autoconfiguration: windows does not download wpad.pac file

Tags: windows, isc-dhcp, wpad

I am trying to configure my dhcp server on Debian Wheezy to reply to DHCP INFORM and send a url where my Windows client may download the wpad.dat file.

Here is the configuration file:

```
option local-proxy-config code 252 = text;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option local-proxy-config "http://192.168.1.85/wpad.dat";
}
```

The client sends a DHCP INFORM and my DHCP server replies with a DHCP ACK:

```
Feb  7 16:40:07 server dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from 192.168.1.99 via eth0
Feb  7 16:40:07 server dhcpd: DHCPACK to 192.168.1.99 (78:92:9c:31:de:26) via eth0
```

However, no HTTP requests are made after the client gets the information about the location of the wpad.dat file.

The autoconfiguration option in Internet Explorer is correctly enabled, and I have reset cache/reinitialized IE configuration multiple times.

When I manually field in IE the location of the wpad file, it gets correctly downloaded, and wpad file gets correctly interpreted (CLient goes then through my proxy), which makes me think the trouble comes from the DHCP ACK not correctly interpreted by Windows.

I don't know how to investigate further, can anyone give me some tip / idea to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote; however any kind of constructive answer would still be rewarded